# Cannot find directories and files created with Phonegap on my Nexus 4

Tags: android, directory, cordova

When using

```
alert(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
```

the output is

```
file:///storage/emulated/0
```

This path exists when I connect the phone to my Computer:

```
Computer\Nexus 4\Internal storage\storage\emulated\0
```

Now I create a directory:

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Test", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
```

The Phonegap feedback is positive, the directory has been created. But on my Nexus 4, the content of

```
file:///storage/emulated/0
```

remains unchanged...

Here's the Phonegap code so you hopefully can understand how I try to do this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                        window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
                        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 2000, gotFS, fail);
                    }, false);

                    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
                        alert(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
                        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Test", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
                    }
                    function success(dir) {
                        alert('Created: ' + dir.toURL());
                        alert(dir.fullPath);
                        //dir.removeRecursively(success, fail);
                    }

                    function fail(error)
                    {
                        alert("Error: " + error.code);
                    }
```

I'm using Eclipse / ADT, my Nexus 4 is connected to my Computer when doing this, obviously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files should be in `/mnt/shell/emulated/0` as viewed from DDMS, `adb shell`, and similar development tools.

With respect to viewing this through the mounted volume, you will need to use [`MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29) to scan files that you place in this directory for them to show up, and even then it may require disconnecting and reconnecting the device, depending upon whether your OS caches the directory information or detects changes.

Comment: Wow, that's it! I found the files with DDMS (on the File Explorer tab), but I still don't know how to get them to show up on my phone. I need the files on my Computer later on, that's why I need to copy them from the phone... How do I achieve that? I don't know how MediaScannerConnection and scanFile() work... Could you help me with that, too?

Comment: @michael_brecker: Sorry, I forgot that you were using PhoneGap/Cordova. Try creating an actual file, beyond just an empty directory, and see if it shows up. `MediaScannerConnection` cannot scan a directory, only actual files. One hopes that Cordova has some hooks to do the `MediaScannerConnection` indexing for you on files that you create.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help! I'll give that a try when I get the chance. So far, I found out that it's possible to edit the data in DDMS itself, only deleting directories is impossible. I'm currently trying to code a file system object that will allow me to write files / create directories by offering just a single string as the path. So I didn't write files, yet. But that will come soon enough! Thanks again for your help, it's much appreciated! I upvoted your answer + marked it as accepted. :)

Comment: My Nexus 4 was updated to Android 4.3 recently. I can access files and folders I create with Phonegap now! So it probably was some kind of Bug? Working as expected now, anyway.